# Is it advantageous using cursor in Oracle for frontend applications?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have two tables in my database. Each table is having 2000 records. As I have a large number of records I would like to write the most optimal code for retrieving records. `USER_DETAILS` table is:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name | join_date |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

The second table which is refering `USER_DETAILS` table is:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| user_id | fav_color | fav_dish  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have two approaches first one:

```
SELECT UD.*,FAV.FAV_COLOR, FAV.FAV_DISH FROM USER_DETAILS UD, FAV_DETAILS FAV 
    WHERE UD.USER_ID = FAV.USER_ID;
```

Second approach is writing a PL/SQL procedure which is:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR C1(X NUMBER) IS SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE USER_ID = X;
CURSOR C2 IS SELECT * FROM USER_FAV;
Y NUMBER := &USER_ID;
BEGIN
FOR C IN C1(Y)
    LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('USER DETAILS');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----------------');
    FOR D IN C2
        LOOP
        IF C.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD(C.USER_ID,10)||RPAD(C.USER_NAME,10)||RPAD(D.FAV_COLOR,10));
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Which code will give better performance and why? I want to get the complete details of a user.

If I am using cursor will I get all the records form the server to the SGA? I will use this database in a JSP page which will be accessed by mobile devices only.

As internet in mobile device is very slow of my target users (around 10KB) hence I am concerned about bandwidth. In my point of view I find that performing a join will do a Cartesian product and check for matching result which will take one condition out of 1000*1000 conditions where as the checking conditions in PL/SQL block is only 1000 + 1000. It reduces the number of conditions. But as per my knowledge cursor will create a shadow page in client memory and it will create the table. This means it will fetch all the data form the server and store in client. Am I correct at this point?

Comment: The queries do two different things. The SELECT gets all users, and the procedure gets a single one. Which of the two are you really trying to do?

Comment: Even though the select is getting all users, I suspect it's faster btw. Replacing joins with loops is very seldom a good idea.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: The join will perform Cartesian product then it will select a row from where the condition is satisfied. So it will iterate for 1000*1000 times. But the loop will not repeat for that many times.

Comment: Create an index on user_id, then the join performs far better.  Without indexes both join and cursor will end up with sequential search, which performs bad.  Also the C2 cursor has to go thru all rows regardless user_id given.  Apparently the join works better.

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi My user_id is a primary key hence index is automatically done by oracle.

Comment: Ah alright.  How about C2 cursor?

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi: It has index too. I have defined it manually

Comment: I mean the C2 cursor does not have `WHERE` conditions. It will loop thru all records.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24738/discussion-between-dibya-and-kenji-noguchi)

Comment: @Dibya Oracle won't perform a cartesian join as long as you connect the tables in an `JOIN/ON` clause or a `WHERE` clause (and you do the latter in your `SELECT`) Some less mature databases may though, so it's good form to use the `JOIN/ON` syntax.

Comment: Side note: 2000 is not a large number of records for Oracle. It isn't even a larger number of records for Access.

Comment: Why in the world would you like to see detail of 2000 accounts on your mobile? You want to see the details of one, perhaps 10 users, not 2000.

Comment: @Plouf: You got my concept wrong. I don't want 2000 records at a time but I will be having 1000 records and 1000 users using simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [here](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.il/2006/10/slow-by-slow.html) Tom Kyte's mantra:

> You should do it in a single SQL statement if at all possible.
>   If you cannot do it in a single SQL Statement, then do it in PL/SQL.
>   If you cannot do it in PL/SQL, try a Java Stored Procedure.
>   If you cannot do it in Java, do it in a C external procedure.
>   If you cannot do it in a C external routine, you might want to seriously think about why it is you need to do it…

Basically by using a plsql stored procedure you move from sql engine to plsql engine back and forward. More then that, if you have the right indexes and you build your query right, the sql optimizer will probably make things faster than you.

[Here is another good AskTom post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:499097979114)

Comment: Thats a good suggestion. I will stick with simple SQL statements but my question isn't solved performance wise which is better at this situation.

Comment: As always - it depends... but as a golden rule - use the sql and not the plsql (that's what the mantra says). Why don't you just try it ? check the explain plans

Comment: Thanks for the AskTom Post. It has a lot of information I needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Generally** using a single select statement will have better performance 
by a single select you will hit RDBMS Sql engine once and RDMS will use internal procedures (indexes, cashed queries ...) boosting performance.

**In programming way** *(ignoring internal RDMS functionality)*
in the first query  you are doing a search with order of efficiency O(n) 
in second plsql statement, by using nested loops you are doing a search with order of efficiency O(n^2) 
[search order of efficiency](http://cset.sp.utoledo.edu/cset3150/cset3150_algo_search.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Use cursor when you want a pointer on each row of your rsult in order to perform further actions. If you just need a `select` statement, just do a `select` statment. Cursor is will be an overkill. Keep it simple.

Comment: Please have a look at my edit part. I have added few more details